# How to print the content of multiple command line arguments on the same line in python?

Tags: python, printing, text-files, command-line-arguments

I want to print the content of multiple command line arguments (text files) on the same line, with a space separating them from one another. This is the code that I've written:

```
from sys import argv, exit

if len(argv) < 2:
    print("Missing command-line argument")
    exit(1)

argumentList = argv[1:]

for arg in argumentList:
    with open(arg, "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
    f.close()
```

It prints each text file on a new line, and that's not what I want. Please, help!

EDIT: Thank you for your help, everyone. I had my question answered!

Comment: Show us a sample of your input and desired output for better understanding.

Comment: If the files contain a newline character at the end, then you will need to strip that off before printing them.  Try using `print(f.read().rstrip(), end=" ")`

Comment: Also didn't work. I added a sample of the input and desired output above

Comment: Oh, so you want to group lines across multiple files, first printing line 1 from each file, then line 2, etc.  You will need to read the files into memory.  You may also need to pad some lines so that the columns line up (i.e. make all the lines in a file the same width).

Comment: Oh. So what you _really_ want is this: Print lines of both files next to each other in a _corresponding_ way.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. And thank you, Tom, I'll try that!

Comment: you will have to split ever text into list of line and use `zip()` to create groups `(file_1_line1, file_2_line1)`, `(file_1_line2, file_2_line2)`, etc. OR you can create 2D list (with rows and columns) and copy `# (one-by-one) from files to correct places in 2D list and later print all lines from this list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split text from every file into list of lines and use `zip()` to create groups `(file_1_line1, file_2_line1)`, `(file_1_line2, file_2_line2)` and print every group in one line

```py
W = """
#     #
#  #  #
# # # #
##   ##
#     #
"""

E = """
#######
#
#######
#
#######
"""

all_lines_W = W.split('\n')
all_lines_E = E.split('\n')

for line_w, line_e in zip(all_lines_W, all_lines_E):
    print(line_w, line_e)
```

Result:

```
#     # #######
#  #  # #
# # # # #######
##   ## #
#     # #######
```

---

For more chars/files you can use lists, `for`-loops and `*args`

```
W = """
#     #
#  #  #
# # # #
##   ##
#     #
"""

E = """
#######
#      
#######
#      
#######
"""

text = [W, E, E, E, W, E, E]
text = [char.split('\n') for char in text]

for lines in zip(*text):
    print(*lines)
```

Result:

```
#     # ####### ####### ####### #     # ####### #######
#  #  # #       #       #       #  #  # #       #      
# # # # ####### ####### ####### # # # # ####### #######
##   ## #       #       #       ##   ## #       #      
#     # ####### ####### ####### #     # ####### #######
```

---

This type of text is called `banner`.

Linux has even special program to display banners on screen (or print on long paper in printer)

Maybe you could even find Python module to display banners. ie. [pyfiglet](https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet)

---

**EDIT:**

Version with data from files

```
from sys import argv, exit

if len(argv) < 2:
    print("Missing command-line argument")
    exit(1)

# --- read ---

text = []

for arg in argv[1:]:
    with open(arg, "r") as f:
        #text.append( f.read() )
        text.append( f.read().split('\n') )

# --- print ---

#text = [char.split('\n') for char in text]

for lines in zip(*text):
    print(*lines)
    #print( " ".join(lines) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, furas. I'm kinda new to programming in general. Can I edit into my post what I've been working with so far, and maybe you can orient me better?

Comment: in my version you have only first read all files and put in list `text`. I added version with `argv`

Answer (score 0):

If you have same number of lines in each files use this code. However, once Python exits from the **“with”** block, the file is automatically closed. So, **don't include close function in "with" block.**

The **readlines()** method returns a list containing each line in the file as a list item. And, the result variable will store lists of each file at each index. **Eg. [file1.readlines(), file2.readlines(), file3.readlines()...]**

*Where, type(result[0]) is list.* Then perform action according to that.

```
from sys import argv, exit

if len(argv) < 2:
    print("Missing command-line argument")
    exit(1)

argumentList = argv[1:]
result = []
for arg in argumentList:
    with open(arg, "r") as f:
        result.append(f.readlines())

total_lines = len(result[0])
total_items = len(result)

# finding maximum space for each file.
maximum_list = []
for item in range(total_items):
    maximum = 0
    for data in range(total_lines):
        result[item][data] = result[item][data].strip("\n")
        length = len(result[item][data])
        if length > maximum:
            maximum = length
    maximum_list.append(maximum)


for i in range(total_lines):
    count = 0
    while count < total_items:
        data = result[count][i]
        length_difference = maximum_list[count] - len(data) # For printing alignment
        print(data + (" " * length_difference), end=" ")
        count += 1
    print()
```

Comment: Yes, all the files have the same number of lines. However, I tried your code and it didn't work. I posted what i've been working with above, would you mind taking a look at it? Either way, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated my code. Please check it once and tell me if its working or not? And, what output it's giving. Now this code will take any number of files and print it.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. The letters look very distorted.

Comment: Yes, It was the mistake in length_difference. I corrected it just check it now.

Comment: Still doesn't work, but interestingly enough, your code spits out the same result as mine now. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Alright, I sent it.